# Generalized prisoners' problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

I am trying to generalize the [prisoner's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem).

The problem reduces to this: find the probability that a random permutation of $1,...,n$ has no cycle of length $>L$.

If the number of permutations with at least one cycle of length $>L$ is, $X$ then the probability is $1-\dfrac{X}{n!}$.

Finding $X$ seems to get messy as there can be more than one cycle in a permutation, so just adding number of cycles of length $i$ for all $i> L$ will count some permutations twice.

Is there any easier approach to this ? Or any way to compute this probability easily for $n,L$?

Comment: Do not forget to mention that you are interested in this only to cheat in the ongoing programming competition.

Answer (score 1):

See [On the number of permutations of $n$ objects with greatest cycle length $k$](https://books.google.de/books?id=Z9kmN_jJ03cC&lpg=PA211&ots=-q7OZt28nM&dq=%22On%20the%20number%20of%20permutations%20of%22%20%22objects%20with%20greatest%20cycle%20length%22&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q&f=false), S.W. Golomb and P. Gaal, p. $211$–$218$ in *Probabilistic Methods in Discrete Mathematics*, V. F. Kolchin et al. (eds.)).

For $\frac n2\lt k\le n$, the number of permutations with greatest cycle length $k$ is $\frac{n!}k$; for $k\lt\frac n2$ the expressions get more complicated. The number of permutations with at least one cycle of length $\gt L$ is the sum of the numbers of permutations with greatest cycle length $l$ for all $l\gt L$.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is a subset of $[1,n]$ then the number $f_S(n)$ of permutations of $[1,n]$ with no cycles of length in $S$ has the generating function:

$$f_S(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} f_S(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}=\texttt{exp}\left({{\sum_{k\in \mathbb N\backslash S}\frac{x^k}{k}}}\right)$$

Now let's compute the number of permutations with no cycle in $S=[1,k]$ we have:
 $$\begin{align} f_{[1,k]}(n)&=&&n! [x^n]\left(\frac{\prod_{j=1}^k\sum_{n\in \mathbb N}\frac{(-1)^nx^{jn}}{n!j^n}}{1-x}\right)
\\ &=&&n!\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{n_1+2n_2+\cdots+kn_k=j}\frac{(-1)^{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k}}{(n_1!1^{n_1})(n_2!2^{n_2})\cdots (n_k!k^{n_k})} \end{align}$$

As you can see the expression is huge,but we can have some approximations :

- $k=1$ the expression gives the number of permutation with no fix-point which is well known, and we get in our sum:
  $$ f_{[1,k]}(n)=n!\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^j}{j!} \underset{n\to \infty}{\sim}\frac{n!}{e^{\frac{1}{1}}} $$
- If we assume that $n$ tends to $+\infty$  than :
  $$ f_{[1,k]}(n)\underset{n\to\infty}{\sim}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{1}}+e^{\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots+e^{\frac{1}{k}}}$$

The relation between this function and your notation is:
$$n!-f_{[1,L]}(n)=X $$